# Php check if arrays inside array contain empty values at specific index

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say we have two 2D array:

```
thisArray = array(
   array('A', 'B', '');
   array('A', 'B', '');
)
```

How to check is thisArrays arrays all have empty values at index 2 and if they do all have empty elements at index 2, how to remove those elements from all arrays?

I can't seem to figure this out and I can't seem to google out any php functions which would help me.

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you already tried yourself and where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), you can achieve this,

`array_column` - gives you array in one direction

`array_filter` - filter, empty values,

So in the end if array is empty, then all are empty

```
<?php

$array = array(
   array('A', 'B', ''),
   array('A', 'B', '')
);

if(empty( array_filter(array_column($array,2))) ){
    echo 'All are empty at index 2'.PHP_EOL;

    // since all are empty
    // use reference and unset
    foreach($array as &$item) {
         unset($item[2]);
    }

    // unset reference 
    unset($item); 
}

print_r($array);
?>
```

Test Results:

```
$ php test.php
All are empty at index 2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisArray = array(
   array('A', 'B', '');
   array('A', 'B', '');
)
```

Try this

```
foreach($thisArray as $array){

if(isset($array[2]) && $array[2]==null){ //if array at index 2 is empty

unset($array[2])); //remove array 
}

}
return $thisArray;
```